# Is it necessary to escape single and double quotes in <p> tags in html?

Tags: html, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I have just installed this WYSIWYG text editor and I found that it wont escape single and double quotes in `<p></p>` tags when I view the html source.

Demo: http://files.wymeditor.org/wymeditor/examples/01-basic.html

Try it for yourself.

I want to know if there is some documents to clarify this problem. Is it necessary?

Comment: Why would it escape quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"` characters need only be represented with entities when used inside attribute values delimited with `"`

`'` characters need only be represented with entities when used inside attribute values delimited with `'`

They can be used as literals inside text nodes.

Comment: Besides, the *correct* quotation marks of human languages, such as “American English” double curly quotes or the angular « French quotes » never need to be escaped, provided that the document’s character encoding allows them to be entered as such, as it should.

Comment: Can you give a reference, please?

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to escape quotes when in text node context (ie. within `body`, `p`, `div` and other such content elements).

Quotes only need escaping when in attribute values and the attribute value is delimited by the same kind of quote.